# Vertx SockJSEventBusBridge Outbound Authentication

Tags: vert.x

I am wondering how to authorise a JS browser client to receive restricted outbound SockJS eventbus messages.

My js client is setup correctly (I think), I have an authorization manager running and working, and the JS client can login and receive a sessionID.

If I add "require_auths" to the SockJSEventBusBridge config outgoing messages are blocked, if I remove that from the config I receive messages.

How do I pass in the sessionID to the registerHandler so the server knows I am allowed receive messages?

JS Code:

```
    var eb = new vertx.EventBus('http://localhost:8080/eventbus');
    eb.onopen = function() { 

      eb.send('vertx.basicauthmanager.login', {username: "user", password: "password"}, function (reply) {
        console.log(reply);            
        if (reply.status === 'ok') {
          console.log(reply.sessionID);
          eb.registerHandler('test.stream', function(message) {
              console.log(message);
          });
        } else {
          alert('invalid login');
        }
      });
    }
```

Server side config (Clojure):

```
    (let [server   (http/server)
          auth-in  [{:address "vertx.basicauthmanager.login"}]
          auth-out [{:address "test.stream"
                     :requires_auth true}]]
      (sockjs/bridge (sockjs/sockjs-server server) {:prefix "/eventbus"} auth-in auth-out)
      (http/listen server 8080 "localhost"))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try to run vertx in debug mode, there are some verbosity in ```EventBusBridge``` that might help. As an option you can debug ```EventBusBridge.internalHandleRegister(...)``` that's the place where auth check is done.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way should be to first obtain sessionID from some authentication provider and then send the sessionID with each message being sent to protected (requiresAuth = true) address. This address will then call handleAuthorise() method of your EventBusBridgeHook to check if the message should be allowed to pass.

After successful authentication and authorization, your session ID gets remembered (cached) for that particular socket. If there is session ID cached for a socket, then all outgoing messages (messages you subscribed to from the client side) will get delivered. **So this means that vert.x checks for the permission to deliver messages at the moment, when there are messages sent/published, not when you register a handler for an address from the client side.**

So this means, that you should first authenticate, then send a message with valid sessionID to some protected address, so that the vertx eventbus bridge caches your session ID. After that, you will be able to receive outbound messages from protected eventbus addresses as well.

I have made some simple demo: https://github.com/michalboska/codingbeer-vertx/tree/auth-experiment (be sure to use auth-experiment branch, the master branch is without any authentication being implemented)

EDIT: The vert.x's behavior is correct, you need to set the sessionId on your javascript eventbus object, e.g.

```
eb.sessionId='abcd.....';
```

https://github.com/eclipse/vert.x/pull/1008

PS: The methods that could be interesting for you in the Vertx core JAR are:
*org.vertx.java.core.sockjs.EventBusBridge#internalHandleRegister*
and
*org.vertx.java.core.sockjs.EventBusBridge#doSendOrPub*